# Не хватает памяти для обработки запроса

Tags: php, sql, yii2

yii2-advanced, база MariaDB. Сделал скрипт, который подтягивает данные из 3 таблиц и сопоставляет данные так:

```
public function matchImage()
{
    $this->image = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'image');
    if ($this->image && $this->validate()) {
        $products = Products::find()->all();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $barcodes = ProductsBarcodes::find()->where(['product_id' => $product->id])->all();
            foreach ($barcodes as $barcode) {
                foreach ($this->image as $image) {
                    $origName = "$image->baseName";
                    $exploded = explode("_", $origName);
                    if (isset($exploded[1])) {
                        $origName = $exploded[0];
                    }
                    if ($origName == $barcode->barcode) {
                        static::newImages($product->id, $image);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


public function newImages($productId, $image)
{
    $array = Images::find()->where(['product_id' => $productId])->all();
    $dir = "uploads/products";
    $num = count($array);
    $name = $productId . "_" . "$num.$image->extension";
    $model = new Images();
    $main = 0;
    foreach ($array as $mainimage) {
        if ($mainimage->main) {
            $main = 1;
        }
    }
    if (!$main) {
        $model->main = 1;
    }
    $model->url = $name;
    $model->product_id = $productId;
    if($model->validate() && $model->save()) {
        $image->saveAs("$dir/$name");
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

На тестовой базе создал эти 3 таблицы, все работает нормально.

На второй тестовой базе (дамп с продакшена) в таблице `products_barcodes` нет поля `id`, т.к. это таблица `one-to-many`.

И вот здесь выпадает ошибка :

```
Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes)
```

`//мало памяти`

Это из-за того, что нету `id`? Можно ли как-то переписать скрипт под таблицу без `id`?

**P.S.**

```
$products = Products::find()->joinWith('product_barcode')->where(['id' => 'product_barcode.product_id'])->all();
public function getProductsBarcodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductsBarcodes::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Comment: в `yii` ассоциаий моделей нет что ли? зачем вы пишите циклы для подгрузки связных записей, если это можно сделать штатными средствами, которые будут портированы в join-запросы, а не выполнять кучу отдельных запросов к БД ?

Comment: @teran, joinWith чтоли? не знаю, мне так проще.

Comment: @teran,  да и yii2 почему то не видит `relations`

Comment: Что значит не видит `relations`? Значит у Вас они неправильно определены

Comment: @teran, посмотрите, что не так с ними? указал в вопросе

Comment: `joinWith` определен не верно, читайте документацию

Comment: @robertobadjo, видимо не совсем понимаю, ведь делаю все с открытой документацией. можно пример или ссылку?

Comment: Для `joinWith` указывается `relation`, а не название таблицы.  В Вашем случае будет `joinWith('productsBarcodes')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно для чего тут нужен `$products = Products::find()->all();`, если у **ProductsBarcodes** есть поле product_id. Первый форич убираем?

Метод **newImage()** хорошо, но ведь он в цикле вызывается, а в нем обращение к БД. Что мешает получить сразу все Images в массив с ключами product_id одним запросом и выбрать не все поля, а только main (судя по коду)?

```
$this->images = Images::find()->select('main')->indexBy('product_id')->all();
```

Затем уже делаем форич `$this->images[$productId]` или обходимся без форича, если выбрать только те записи, у которых main больше 0 (или что там должно быть). Достаточно будет проверить наличие `$this->images[$productId]` и не надо будет каждый раз перебирать массив, и сам массив будет меньше.

Уверен, что это значительно снизит прожорливость.

Comment: вы предлагаете *перед циклом* собирать массив? но ведь таблица заполняется по мере работы цикла, и количество изображений растет, а так же поле main может изменяться. и каждый раз цикл будет использовать массив без новых строк. разве не так?

Comment: насчет форича для images: мне нужен count массива картинок, поэтому либо форич, либо еще 1 запрос. можно ли объединить запросы так, чтобы узнать, есть ли main=1 у products_id и количество записей с ним же?

Comment: В массив можно пушить новые данные, чтобы он обновлялся после каждой итерации. $cnt = count($array), чтобы без форича и еще одного запроса.