# Не работают relations

Tags: php, yii2

yii2-advanced, не работают `relations`.

Метод (сгенерированный `gii`):

```
public function getProductsBarcodes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProductsBarcodes::className(), ['product_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Попытка сделать запрос:

```
$products = Products::find()->joinWith('product_barcode')->where(['id' => 'product_barcode.product_id'])->all();
```

Ошибка:

```
frontend\models\Products has no relation named "product_barcode".
```

Comment: У вас в продукте может быть несколько баркодов?

Comment: да, а это как-то влияет на склеивание?

Comment: да. Join вернет несколько записей одного и того же продукта, но с разными баркодами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$products = Products::find()
    ->joinWith('productsBarcodes')
    ->all();
```

Comment: не знаю, что я делаю не так, но это не работает

Comment: @dasauser ошибку покажите хотя бы

Comment: нет ошибки. поставлю по другому вопрос: как скрипт из моего вопроса про нехватку памяти отрефакторить так, чтобы из двойного запроса таблиц из базы сделать одинарный по joinWith?  я не понимаю, как это сделать. ссылка: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/882593/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0

Comment: Надо вместо циклов слепить одну таблицу. Еще как вариант выбрать два массива, а потом уже перебирать один из них и работать с другим. Разнести некоторые куски кода по методам, чтобы память подчищалась.

Comment: @fedornabilkin, я понял что надо делать, но не знаю как. как слепить одну таблицу? два массива и так выбираются и перебираются, код по ссылке. кусок кода вынес в метод, остальное не получится.

Comment: @Modder, возвращается пустой массив.

Comment: да и даже если получается склеить таблицы, то выходит ошибка `Primary key of 'frontend\models\ProductsBarcodes' can not be empty.`, от которой я изначально и пытался уйти.

Comment: @dasauser попробуйте без `where`. Вернет все записи в таблице.

Comment: @Modder, будет ошибка, из-за которой я открыл предыдущий вопрос. но, к счастью, в том вопросе оказалось, что я просто по глупости написал лишний код.

Comment: в принципе, это сработало, если указывать id product напрямую